# ssl.SSLError: [SSL: BAD_LENGTH] bad length (_ssl.c:2483) from gevent when mqtt payload size is more than 100kb

Tags: flask, ssl, mqtt, gunicorn, gevent

I have a Python Flask app that publishes messages to the MQTT topic and subscribes from the MQTT topic. It is deployed on Kubernetes and runs on gunicorn with the gevent worker class.

The app creates two Paho mqttv5 clients for each publishing and subscribing to the messages and the client uses TLS default context.

My custom Paho client code:

```
@attr.s
class PahoClient:
    KEEPALIVE_IN_SECONDS = 60
    _message_bus_host = attr.ib(type=str, default=None)
    _message_bus_port = attr.ib(type=int, default=None)
    client_id = attr.ib(type=str, default=None)
    username = attr.ib(type=str, default=None)
    password = attr.ib(type=str, default=None)
    connected = attr.ib(type=bool, default=False)
    _unexpected_disconnect = attr.ib(type=bool, default=False)

    def __attrs_post_init__(self):
        self._client = Client(client_id=self.client_id, userdata=id, protocol=MQTTv5)
        if self.username and self.password:
           self._client.username_pw_set(username=self.username, password=self.password)
           self._client.tls_set_context(context=ssl.create_default_context())

        self._client.on_connect = self._on_connect
        self._client.on_publish = self._on_publish
        self._client.on_message = self._handle_message
        self._client.on_disconnect = self._on_disconnect
        self._log_on = self.on_log

    def on_log(self, client, userdata, level, buf):
        logger.debug(f"log {buf}")

    def loop(self):
        if self.loop_in_own_thread:
            raise ValueError("Can't call loop if connector is running in its own thread")
        self._client.loop()

    def connect(self):
        self._client.connect(host=self._message_bus_host, port=self._message_bus_port,
                             keepalive=self.KEEPALIVE_IN_SECONDS)

        # runs a thread in the background to call loop() automatically
        if self.loop_in_own_thread:
            self._client.loop_start()

    def disconnect(self):
        # disconnect client from broker
        self._client.disconnect()

        # stop thread
        if self.loop_in_own_thread:
            self._client.loop_stop()

    def _register_callback(self, topic: str, callback: Callable):
        self._client.message_callback_add(topic, callback)
        self._client.subscribe(topic=topic)

    def subscribe(self, subscriptions: List[Type['Subscription']]) -> None:
        """
        Register callbacks for all subscriptions.
        """
        for subscription in subscriptions:
            if subscription not in self._subscriptions:
                self._subscriptions.append(subscription)
        # add callbacks for new subscriptions
        for subscription in subscriptions:
            self._register_callback(subscription.target, subscription.callback.callback)

    def send_message(self, message: MqttMessage) -> MQTTMessageInfo:
        return self._client.publish(topic=message.resource,
                                    payload=payload,
                                    qos=message.quality_of_service,
                                    retain=message.retain)

    def _handle_message(self, client, userdata, message):
        """
        Message handler for all topics which have no explicit handlers subscribed to.
        """
        logger.debug("Received unsubscribed message %s" % message.payload)

    def _on_publish(self, client, userdata, mid):
        logger.debug("on_publish for client {0}, mid {1}".format(self.client_id, mid))

    def _on_connect(self, client, userdata, flags, rc, properties):
        """
        The callback for when the client receives a CONNACK response from the server.
        """

        logger.info("%s connected with result code %s to broker %s:%d" % (self.client_id, rc,
                                                                          self._client.socket().getpeername()[0],
                                                                          self._client.socket().getpeername()[1]))
        self.connected = True
        if self._unexpected_disconnect:
            logger.info(f"re-subscribing to {self._subscriptions} topics")
            # Re-register subscriptions after disconnect
            self.subscribe(self._subscriptions)
            self._unexpected_disconnect = False

    def _on_disconnect(self, client, userdata, rc, properties):
        if rc != 0:
            logger.warning(f"Unexpected message bus disconnection, code {rc}, {self._client._client_id}")
            self.connected = False
            if rc == 1:
                logger.warning("Possibly there is already another client connected with the same identifier")
            self._unexpected_disconnect = True

            logger.info(f"Trying to reconnect {self._client._client_id}")
            self.connect()
```

The issue is Paho mqtt client throws the following error when the app publishes more than 100kb messages. The app keeps publishing messages without any error but no callback method gets called. The paho-mqtt client throws this error only when the app runs on Gunicorn with gevent worker class.

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 910, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 3591, in _thread_main
    self.loop_forever(retry_first_connection=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 1756, in loop_forever
    rc = self._loop(timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 1181, in _loop
    rc = self.loop_write()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 1577, in loop_write
    rc = self._packet_write()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 2464, in _packet_write
    write_length = self._sock_send(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 649, in _sock_send
    return self._sock.send(buf)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gevent/_ssl3.py", line 501, in send
    return self._sslobj.write(data)
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: BAD_LENGTH] bad length (_ssl.c:2483)
```

**The gunicorn command in kuberenetes looks like below:**

```
 spec:
      containers:
        - name: mqtt-flask-app
          image: <docker image>
          command:
            - bash
            - '-c'
            - gunicorn wsgi -w 1 -b :5000 -t 600 --worker-class gevent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5000
              protocol: TCP
```

It works fine after deploying app on kubernetes by removing gevent package from requirements.txt and worker-class option from gunicorn command in Kubernetes deployment like below.

```
 spec:
      containers:
        - name: mqtt-flask-app
          image: <docker image>
          command:
            - bash
            - '-c'
            - gunicorn wsgi -w 1 -b :5000 -t 600
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5000
              protocol: TCP
```

I have to run Flask app on Gunicorn with gevent worker class. Could please suggest solution for this issue?

Comment: There is an [open issue](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/issues/637) for this with some suggestions (but no real answer - also [this](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/issues/637) and [this](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/issues/691)).

Comment: Thank @Brits for your answer. Those links did not help. The eventlet works fine. So I am thinking of using it.